# What is the purpose of the Human Instrumentality Project?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

The Human Instrumentality Project is one of the main plotlines in the Neon Genesis Evangelion original series. However, other than a few speculative mentions, there isn't concrete information as to what purpose it serves.

What purpose does the Human Instrumentality Project serve, why is it necessary, and what part does it plays against the Angels (if any)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The ultimate goal is to unite all the individual souls of mankind into one singular being.

This would create an existence where nobody existed individually, but as part of a whole.

This way, the flaws in every living being would be complemented by the strengths in others, thus erasing the insecurities in people's hearts. Creating the ultimate, god-like being.

To achieve Instrumentality, the merging of Adam and Lilith, resulting in the Third Impact, is required.

Both [Seele](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Third_Impact#Seele.27s_version) and [Gendo](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Third_Impact#Gendo_Ikari.27s_version) had their own idea of instrumentality. Neither was [realized](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Third_Impact#Actual_Third_Impact).

Comment: But, how does creating this God-like being stop the Angels from trying to exterminate us?

Comment: They are not trying to exterminate humans, they are merely trying to reunite with Adam. The Angels don't care about Instrumentality.

Comment: i should also point out that it's hinted throughout the series that the Angels was always going after Adam as to the reason why an Angel attacked the Naval Fleet that was transporting Eva 2 (Adam was being held by Kenji who was on the fleet), the fact everyone was lead to believe that the angel impaled on the Lance was Adam (but was actully Lilith) and Kaworu making his way into Terminal Dogma believing Adam was there but only finding Lilith

Answer (score 0):

Angels are trying to merge with Adam to restore their power on earth. The Ancestral race sent Adam to colony planet Earth with his seeds (the Angels). It was due to the First Impact that Lilith got in Adam's way. She was on her way to another planet and crashed on Earth, stopping Adam. Now, Adam and his descendants just try to reclaim earth from mankind - the seed of Lilith.

Seele accepted that the humans do actually not have the right to live on earth due to the information they got out of the Second Impact (Reawakening of Adam) and the Dead Sea Scrolls. But they do not want to kill all humans either. So they try to bring together Lilith and Adam in order to develop a new entity that absorbs all humans into one godlike entity (similar to the Angels - Humans are viewed as the final Angel Lilin). In this form humans have actually the right to live on Earth because they are created by the unity of Lilith and Adam. In order to achieve this Seele wanted to merge Kaworu, an Angel and the carrier of Adam's soul, with Lilith. This would be the Third Impact. The whole plan is called the Human Instrumentality Project. Gendo just wants to reunite with his dead wife, Shinji's mother, which is "his" idea of the Human Instrumentality Project. He injects himself the embryo of Adam in order to merge with Lilith. Some years ago, his wife tried to merge with Lilith in order to revive her and disappeared in the process (but she still exists inside Lilith's body). Gendo is later killed by Rei (a humanlike clone of Lilith/Gendo's wife). He sacrified and abandoned his son Shinji to the Angels in order to achieve his goals which was not the will of his dead wife who punished him through the hands of Rei (her "daughter" if you want to put it like that).

Comment: Can you give some sources for your information? I remember bits of this happening in End of Eva, but a lot of it isn't ringing any bells.